# i want to put a limit on my textbox numirec and 1-10 only

Tags: javascript

put a limit 1-10 cant put 11,12,13,14,15,etc.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 2 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

Comment: What database are you using? What code have you already tried and what do you already have? Please edit and include this so we can help you.

Comment: **Please send me your source code**... No, we won't send anything without seeing what you've tried. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before asking.

Comment: im using a mysql database.. i post my source code.. the output of that is to view all data from database... my only problem is how do i calculate the in deffirent rows..

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the number of rows in the database. You can use this code if you are using MYSQL Database:

```
<?php
db_connect();//class connection to the database

//query the database and count
$sql = "select * from tablename";
$res = mysqli_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

//display the result
echo $num_rows;
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated is going to be removed in PHP very soon. Use mysqli_* instead. (Read the big red box: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

to count mysql rows result you can use `mysqli_num_rows($query)`
example :

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 1");

$active_users = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo $active_users . 'Are activated on your site';

?>
```